# vb.net - TCP sender/listener not working outside of single machine

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

I've got a simple app that i'm enabling for tcp comms.

I've added a listener on the client for port 60123 on system.net.ipaddress.any.

The listener is started shortly after the app launches like so...

```
Public Function StartListener()
    Try
        Listener.Start()
        TCPListener_Timer.Start()
        DoLogging("TCP Listener initiated. Awaiting comms on port " & TCP_Port)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrHandling(ex.message.ToString)
    End Try
End Function
```

The 'sender' for now is a really simple app that asks for IP, port and message and sends the message like so...

```
     Public Function MessageClient(ByVal host As String, ByVal port As String, ByVal Message As String)
    Try
        Client = New TcpClient
        Client.SendTimeout = 2500
        Client.ReceiveTimeout = 2500
        Client.Connect(host, port)
        Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream())

        Writer.Write(Message)
        Writer.Flush()
        Client.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        DoLogging(Errorresult)
    End Try
End Function
```

If i run both the sender and the client on the same machine and send a message from the client it works perfectly. The client received the message and everything is good.

If I try sending the message by running the sender on another machine (same local network, same subnet etc), it does not work. I end up with a System.Net.Sockets.SocketException because 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'.

**things i've tried so far with no luck...**

- Binding the listener to a specific IP.
- Using different ports for the listener.
- Allowing the relevant ports through windows firewall on both sides.
- disabling windows firewall on both sides.
- Packet inspection with WireShark - I can see the handshake request going out but no returned ACK. Inspection on the receiving end shows nothing.

Has anyone had this type of issue before that might be able to point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you send the Tcp Listener code too ? I think that i know your problem